# How to check at compile-time inheritance using std::enable_if_t & std::is_base_of for SFINAE?

Tags: templates, c++14, sfinae, type-traits

I'm trying to restrict the template type of a function to a specific class and their subclasses at compile time. To accomplish this, I'm using the type traits `std::enable_if_t` and `std::is_base_of` like this:

```
template <typename T = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A, T> > >
```

But the template still compiles with types which are not part of the inheritance hierarchy (i.e. `int`). Below is an MCVE of the problem:

```
class A {
public:
  A(float a) : a(a) {}
  float a;
};
class B : public A{
public:
  B(float a) : A(a) {}
};

template <typename T = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A, T> > >
void templateFunction(T a) {

}

int main() {
  templateFunction<A>(A(1.0f)); // OK -> std::is_base_of<A, A>
  templateFunction<B>(B(1.0f)); // OK -> std::is_base_of<A, B>

  templateFunction<int>(1); // Should not compile! int is not a subclass of A -> std::is_base_of<A, int>
  return 0;
}
```

This compiles under Visual Studio 2017 without any error, but the last instantiation of the template function should not compile in my understanding.
Is there any problem in my usage of the type traits or is there a problem with Visual Studios SFINAE implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your use of enable_if is a bit weird, I would have done the following:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value> templateFunction(T a) {

}
```

Even better solution: forget about SFINAE altogether:

```
template <typename T>
void templateFunction(T a) {
  static_assert(std::is_baseOf<A,T>(), "only subclasses, please");
}
```

**Edit, explanation:** think of enable_if_t as something that becomes a type if the condition is met (defaulting to `void`).

Applying this, your function reads as:

```
// true case:
template <typename T = void>
void templateFunction(T a) {}

// false case:
template <typename T = nonsense>
void templateFunction(T a) {}
```

Your invocation still matches the template in the false case!

Now, applying this to my suggested code:

```
//true case:
template <typename T>
void templateFunction(T a) {}

//false case:
template <typename T>
*nonsense* templateFunction(T a) {}
```

Here, the function cannot exists at all in the false case, so it creates a compilation error.